# Xcode will continue when AppleTV is connected

Tags: macos, connection, device, locked

I seem to do everything right: I connect AppleTV to the same wi-fi as my Mac, but when trying to deploy to AppleTV, Xcode says "Xcode will continue when AppleTV is connected".

The same thing happens when I connect AppleTV and my Mac via the cable!

If I go to "Devices and Simulators" option, it says AppleTV is locked.

This does not look like a "real" problem because I sometimes am successful on deploying, but these errors keep coming back after one or two successful deployments...

What am I doing wrong? Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be a hardware issue: I bought a new AppleTV, everything worked fine.
At times though the connection gets lost. The troubleshooting for that is re-pair AppleTV and Mac. You probably will need to also restart the Mac as the UI does not always allow to unpair the connected devices.